# XML get certain data from node in Matlab 2015b

Tags: xml, matlab, readxml, dom-node

I have parsed an xml node into my MATLAB project with the following information:

```
      Name: '#text'
Attributes: []
      Data: '500'
  Children: []
```

I can easily acess the name of the node using `node.getNodeName`.

Now I want to read the data out of this node, but I don't get MATLAB to do this.

I tried:

```
dataString=node.getData;
```

and

```
dataString=char(node.getData);
```

In both cases I got this error:

```
Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
```

What went wrong with my code?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Sorry, If forgot to post. The **error** is: `Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.`

Comment: That error message surprises me, because your code does not contain any dynamic field names. Can you upload an example file and the code you are using?

Comment: @Daniel I have my example files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a28rz22w70q1ol3/AACpv5zUkz2a1rKj63m_YGbza?dl=0). One xml-file to parse and the m-file.
The code structure is from [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To precise my comments, your question did not contain any dynamic field names, but your code does!

The relevant code lines are the two lines

```
struct1.(theChild.getNodeName)=char(nameChild.getData);
```

Here `theChild.getNodeName` is of type `java.lang.String` and not of type `char`. Use this line instead:

```
struct1.(char(theChild.getNodeName))=char(nameChild.getData);
```